# SSL connection broken to Google Cloud SQL in Go 1.15

Tags: mysql, go, ssl, google-cloud-sql, x509

A new Go version has been released recently (1.15) which broke the `ServerName` in TLS config. When using the default `project-name:db-name`, the connection fails with error `x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match project-name:db-name`. While debugging I've found out that this issue is being caused by this [commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/f81aa23cf04f2be5fd2159e855e185b2d75ba503). The commit removes `:` from valid characters in the Hostname/ServerName.

Did anyone get their Go 1.15 application to connect to Cloud SQL via SSL?

Comment: `project-name:db-name` is definitely not a valid server name. How was this certificate created?

Comment: I've created the keys through the Google Cloud Console and used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53752416/12896948 as reference for implementation in go.

Comment: it might be worth creating an issue on the go repo directly since the developers will probaly be aware of a workaround or identify a bug

Comment: Created https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40748